# AndEngine No Music on menu

Tags: android, andengine

I have a simple `MenuScene` which I want to add background music to but after setting up the audio source and calling play on my music object, I get no audio. In the logcat I get this error

`W/AudioTrack﹕ obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?) 0xb96465f8 name=0x3user=00001ce0, server=00000c60
09-13 21:17:36.037      102-322/? W/AudioFlinger﹕ write blocked for 9946 msecs, 10 delayed writes, thread 0xb9628c00`

My code:

```
 private void loadMenuAudio() {
    MusicFactory.setAssetBasePath("sound/");  
    try {
        mMusic = MusicFactory.createMusicFromAsset(engine.getMusicManager(), activity, "sure.wav");
        mMusic.play();
        mMusic.setLooping(true);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Debug.e(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

The menu shows up fine and is working but I get no audio. I already set the engine options for `needMusic` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

You have to  load all the resources(like sounds, music, Textures) in onLoadResources() method before you enter into the scenes because these resources will take time to load. 
So place loadMenuAudio() method in onLoadResources() and run this method on uiThread.
 i.e..

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                loadMenuAudio();                
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I had tried this, still no audio although this was on the genymotion nexus emulator. I tested it on the tablet emulator and I do hear sound. Not sure if this adds any good news for my situation.